# why I cannot get correct date from array?

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]Why I can't get the correct date from the array?

I tried to get the correct date from the array, I use Log.d methods, the date has in the array, but when I click the listener, I always get the last date. where is the problem?

Below is my code:

```
private void loadMaps() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Load...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_MAPSHOW,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String showmaplocation) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(showmaplocation);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("map");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject mapShow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                mapShowArrayList.add(new MapShow(
                                        mapShow.getInt("MapID"),
                                        mapShow.getInt("UserID"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapLat"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapLng"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapTitle"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapPhoto"),
                                        mapShow.getInt("MapType")
                                ));
                                
                                final String info = mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle();
                                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getLat());
                                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getLng());
                                //Log.d("data:" , latitude +"," + longitude);
                                LatLng nowlocat = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                //Log.d("Location", String.valueOf(nowlocat));

                                switch (mapShowArrayList.get(i).getMtype()) {
                                    case 1: 
                                        icon = R.drawable.police; 
                                        break;
                                    case 2: 
                                        icon = R.drawable.ambulance; 
                                        break;
                                    case 3: 
                                        icon = R.drawable.firetruck; 
                                        break;
                                }

                                boolean imageCreated = false;
                                Bitmap bmp = null;
                                imageCreated = true;
                                Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 120, conf);
                                Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);
                                Paint color = new Paint();
                                Paint wordcolor = new Paint();
                                color.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF); 
                                color.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT); 
                                wordcolor.setTextSize(30);
                                int width = (int)wordcolor.measureText(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle());         
                                color.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                wordcolor.setColor(Color.BLACK);


                                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                opt.inMutable = true;
                                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), icon,opt);                              
                                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 80, 80, true);
                                canvas1.drawBitmap(resized, 40, 40, color);
                                canvas1.drawRoundRect(new RectF(30,-40,width+50,50),10,10, color);
                                canvas1.drawText(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), 40, 40, wordcolor);
                                URLIMAGE = mapShowArrayList.get(i).getiConPicture();
                                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                                        .draggable(false)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) 
                                        .position(nowlocat);


                                marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                                marker.showInfoWindow();

                                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Reading Detail. " + error.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

the below line can get the correct date

```
final String info = mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle()
```

but there, I always get the last date.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
```

cannot get value i in the  `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener`

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject mapShow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                mapShowArrayList.add(new MapShow(
                                        mapShow.getInt("MapID"),
                                        mapShow.getInt("UserID"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapLat"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapLng"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapTitle"),
                                        mapShow.getString("MapPhoto"),
                                        mapShow.getInt("MapType")
                                ));
                                //double nowLocation = Double.compare(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getMapLatLng());
                                //ObjectList A[0] =

                                info = mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle();

                                Log.d("INFO", info);

                                
                                
                                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
```

```
error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

CustomObject.java

```
public class CustomObject {
    private int MapID;
    private int UserID;
    private String Lat;
    private String Lng;
    private String title;
    private String iConPicture;
    private int Mtype;

    public CustomObject(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public CustomObject() {
    }

    public int getMapID() {
        return MapID;
    }

    public void setMapID(int mapID) {
        MapID = mapID;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return Lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        Lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return Lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        Lng = lng;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getiConPicture() {
        return iConPicture;
    }

    public void setiConPicture(String iConPicture) {
        this.iConPicture = iConPicture;
    }

    public int getMtype() {
        return Mtype;
    }

    public void setMtype(int mtype) {
        Mtype = mtype;
    }
```

I using this methods, I will get error  com.stanley.ifunpot.models.CustomObject.getTitle()' on a null object reference

code

```
private CustomObject customObject;

MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title(customObject.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) .position(nowlocat);

                                marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                                marker.setTag(new CustomObject(MAP_ID,MapLat,MapLng,MapTitle,MapPhoto,MapType));
                                marker.showInfoWindow();

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        CustomObject data = (CustomObject) marker.getTag();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(data.getMtype()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return false;
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: is `info` having the same value as in `mapShow.getString("MapTitle")`?

Comment: yes, I can get the value form mapShow.getString("MapTitle"), but when I put mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle() in mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener will get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title("Marker Title").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) .position(nowlocat);

marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
marker.setTag(new CustomObject());
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

and at the time of retrieving it you can try following:-

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                     CustomObject data = (CustomObject) amarker.getTag();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),data.getInfo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
```

where youcan out all your needy stuff like `info`,`latitude`,`longitude`,etc inside `CustomObject` and retrieve as shown.

Comment: need to create new CustomObject class?  @Nadeem Shaikh

Comment: @Stanley Yes create any custom object and populate all the required stuff that you need to associate with the marker.

Comment: Last question, how can show every marker title in google map at all time?

Comment: @Stanley Check the code now. You can set title of the marker at the time of initializing `MarkerOptions`

Comment: I have set "MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title(mapShowArrayList.get(i).getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) .position(nowlocat);", but it's only show last marker title

Comment: @Stanley inside title of MarkerOptions retrieve the title that you have set in CustomObject class using getTitle() of CustomObject...so the MarkerOptions will look like this - MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title(customObject.getTitle())....... And so on

Comment: please check the text, I have update new informatino @Nadeem Shaikh

Comment: Create new CustomObject that you are creating in setTag before the MarkerOptions statement

Comment: marker.setTag(new CustomObject2(new_title));
                                CustomObject2 data2 = (CustomObject2) marker.getTag();
                                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title(data2.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) .position(nowlocat);


get error 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
private CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(MAP_ID,MapLat,MapLng,MapTitle,MapPhoto,MapType);
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().draggable(false).title(customObject.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) .position(nowlocat);
marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                            marker.setTag(customObject);
                            marker.showInfoWindow();
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                    CustomObject data = (CustomObject) marker.getTag();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(data.getMtype()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
```

Do like this in your code!